# Azure Data Factory (Self Hosted IR)

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

While trying to register self-hosted IR on my local machine (on-premises) I am getting the below error:

[image]

When tried to investigate the log it says "Specified path not found" :
[image]

I would like to hear if someone has come across this error and what was the remediation.

Comment: Does this help - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/self-hosted-integration-runtime-troubleshoot-guide#self-hosted-ir-could-not-load-file-or-assembly?

Comment: I did try the above Microsoft link  but didn't work.

Comment: @yvr238y can you try delete the the self-hosted IR on Portal? Re-created it  and install again.

Comment: I didn't delete IR from portal multiple times and re-installed with no luck.